HTML Hyperlink with 2 different links (for desktop and mobile)
I'm trying to make a hyperlink with 2 different links where for desktop version it would be lets say:
<a class="dynamic-link" href="www.test.sk/desktop">Link</a>

and for mobile version it will be:
<a class="dynamic-link" href="www.test.sk/mobile">Link</a>

I'm pretty sure, it can be done by javaScript. But I am looking for some efficient way, so I can apply this to multiple hyperlinks with different classes etc.
I tried it with some media queries through javaScript, but it was too complex

let me say you are using a strange approach.. I mean it's very unpopular to have something like that with an anchor element point at dynamic url depending on the client being mobile or desktop. Usually the approach is having a responsive design that will just render the page according to the screen real estate. Anyway yes it can be done.. even just by changing the href attribute of the given element via javascript on document ready.. but how are you going to discerne the client? via navigator.userAgent? media queries you talked about target media qualities like screen resolution instead

If you are "pretty sure, it can be done by javascript", why don't you give it a try and post your code here so we can help you out with it. That is better than just straight up asking us to do all the work for you, you learn more and ask less of the folks trying to help you.

It is an inaccessible approach. Besides that, how do you want to find out that somebody is using a mobile device.

You can display it like
<a class="dynamic-link" href="www.test.sk/desktop">Link</a>

and have a Javascript code like
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    if (isMobile()) {
        for (let link of document.querySelectorAll("dynamic-link")) {
            link.href = link.href.replace("desktop", "mobile");
        }
    }
});

The only thing that remains to be solved is the way you can find out whether the browser is mobile. Luckily this is well-documented. For example: https://github.com/kaimallea/isMobile
